# Considering Axon in greenfield project

Tags: domain-driven-design, axon

I'll be starting on a greenfield project in a few months. 
The project will contain lot's of business logic, spread over several `subdomains`. Yes, we'll be using principles of `Domain Driven Design`.
Tech will consist of `Spring, Spring Boot & Hibernate` stack.

I was looking after some Java libs to cover infrastructural things like:

- `domain event publication`
- `event store`
- `event deduplication`
- `resequencers` on consumer side
- `projections`
- `reliable publishing`
- `reliable delivery & redelivery`
- ...

I came across the `Axon Framework`. I already heard about it, didn't know it in details. So I read some blogposts, little bit of documentation and watched some broadcasts on Youtube.

It seems very promising, I'm considering to use it because I don't want to reinvent to wheel over and over again on the infrastructural side.
So I'm looking for someone to answer and clarify my questions:

### Command handling

Axon use `CommandHandlers` with `void` methods. Is it possible to make them return a value (for instance a generated business id) or objects for notification purposes concerning the business operation? 
It's not a issue to me that the method will be I/O blocking by this.

### Local vs remote domain events publication

I want to have a clear separation of `local` vs `remote` domain events. 
`Local domain` events should only be visible and consumed to the local subdomain. Is it possible to configure event consumption sync and/or async?
My Local domain events can be 'fat'. They are allowed to carry more data because it won't cross the domain boundaries.

`Remote domain events` will be 'thin', so only the minimum data necessary for remote domains. This type op events need always to be handles async.

Is it possible to convert a local (fat) domain event to a remote (thin) domain event at the edge of a domain? By 'edge', I mean the infrastructural side.
By this, the domain model doesn't need to know distinction between local & remote domain events.

### CQRS synchronously

My application will consist of 1 (maybe 2) `core domains` and `several subdomains`. Some domains contain lot's of business logic and will require `CQRS`.
Other domain will be more 'crudy' style.
Is it possible to do `CQRS` synchronously?
 I want to start this way before adding technical complexities like async handling. It this plossible with `Axon`?
This also means that domain events will be stored in a events store without using `event sourcing`.
 Can Axon's `event store` be used without event sourcing?
Same for projection stuff, I just want to projection domain events to build my read model.

### Modular monolith

We'll use a `modular monolith`. 
Not very trendy these days with all the `microservices` stuff. Although, I'm convinced of having a monolith where each domain is completely separated (application code & DB-schema), where operations will be handled with eventual consistency and domain events contain the necessary data. 
Later on, and if necessary, it will be easier to migrate to a `microservices architecture`.
Is Axon a framework that fits in a modular monolith kind of architecture? Is there anything to take into account?

### Fully separated domain model (persistence agnostic)

The domain model will be completely separated from the data model. 
We need to have a repository that reads a data model (using `Hibernate`) and uses a `data mapper` to create an aggregate when it needs to be loaded.
The other way is also needed, an aggregate needs to be converted and saved into the data model (using data mapper). 
Additionally, the aggregates's domain events need to be stored into an event store and published to local or remote event handlers.

This has some consequences:

- we need to have full control of repository implementation that communicates with one or more DAO's (Spring data repositories) to take the necessary data out of Hibernate entities and construct an aggregate with it. An aggregate might be modeled in 2 or even 3 relational tables after all.
- we don't need any Hibernate annotation in the domain model

Is this approach possible with Axon? I only see examples using direct JPA (domain model maps 1 to 1 to entities) or event sourcing.
*This approach is really a deal breaker for us, a separated domain model gives so much more possibilities than mapping it directly to data entities.*

Below an example of what I want to achieve:

Aggregate (without JPA) in some domain model package:

```
public class ScoringResultAggregate {
  // members, constructor, operation omitted for brevity
}
```

Hibernate Entity in some infrastructure package:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="SOME_TABLE_NAME)
public class ScoringResultEntity {
  // member and getters & setters; no domain logic
}
```

Repository interface that belongs to the domain model:

```
public interface ScoringResultRepository {
  void save(ScoringResultAggregate scoringResultAggregate);

  ScoringResultAggregate findByApplicationNumber(ApplicationNumber applicationNumber);
}
```

Adapter that implements repository interface; responsible for mapping aggregate from/to data (JPA) model:

```
class ScoringResultAdapterRepository implements ScoringResultRepository {
  private ScoringResultJpaRepository scoringResultJpaRepository;

  ScoringResultJPARepository(ScoringResultJpaRepository scoringResultJpaRepository) {
    this.scoringResultJpaRepository= scoringResultJpaRepository;

  public void save(ScoringResultAggregate scoringResultAggregate) {
    // converts aggregate to ScoringResultEntity and saves the state into DB
  }

  public ScoringResultAggregate findByApplicationNumber(ApplicationNumber applicationNumber) {
    // loads an ScoringResultEntity from DB and converts it into an aggregate
  }
}
```

### Axon Server

`Axon server` looks very promising. Although, is it only useful for `event sourcing`?
Can it be used together with a Sql DB where aggregates are stored (state persistence) and domain events get persisted in Axon Server?

Lot of questions. Hopefully, someone with Axon experience can help me out :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel Jasper is saying the right things, but I also think I can emphasize them a little more:

- **Command handling** - Yes you can have return values on command handlers. Just be mindful that you do no abuse this to return state of the to the user, as that would be mixing the Command Model (your Aggregate handling the command) with your Query Model.
- **Local vs remote domain events publication** - Jasper states this clearly and he's right. Your hitting the desire to form bounded context's, for which Axon Server (Enterprise) has support. If you'd not use Axon, you'll have to build this infrastructure yourself.
- **CQRS synchronously** - Axon provides handles for asynchronous and synchronous messaging just fine. The main difference is that you'll block on the result of sending your messages. The `CommandGateway` for example has a `send` and `sendAndWait` method, thus providing you with sync and async command dispatching. Lastly, it's perfectly fine to use Axon Server as the event store without doing Event Sourcing. Event Sourcing is an choice when using Axon, not a requirement.
- **Modular monolith** - AxonIQ as a company actively encourages this approach to building software. So yes, you can do this, and no, I cannot think of anything you should think of prior to doing this.
- **Fully separated domain model (persistence agnostic)** - From your Query Model you have full control over how you'd want to map your data model to and from the actual model you'd use. The Aggregate in Axon terms should be regarded as your Command Model, for which you can choose the Event Sourced storage approach or the State Stored storage approach. The state-stored implementation given by Axon Framework works based on JPA, which would thus require you to set some annotations along side the axon annotations in your Command Model. If you need to segregate this, I could imagine you'd create your own variant of the `Repository` and `AggregateFactory`. Then again, the Event Sourcing approach would make your domain model clear of persistence annotations altogether, so I'd go for that route to be honest.
- **Axon Server** - Yes you can use Axon Server even if you go the state-stored approach for Aggregates. Know that Axon Server next to being an event store is a unified routing solution for commands, events and queries. If you would move from a modular monolith to a (micro) services set up, having Axon Server in place to perform all the message routing will make your life very, very easy.

Comment: Hi Steven, thx for your time to answer my questions. I've added a simplified example regarding the separated domain model for clarity. Concerning Event Sourcing, I've very little uses cases where ES is necessary. That's why the aggregates 'll be 'state-stored' instead of 'event stored'. CQRS 'll be used, although most of it synchronously (initially). Do you have any clue how much work (and complexity) a custom Repository & AggregateFactory includes?

Comment: To be honest with you @user2054927, I think event sourcing your aggregate would fit perfectly with your "Fully separated domain model (persistence agnostic)" question, as it uses a completely different model for the domain opposed to the persistence approach.
Another benefit of doing event sourcing would be that you're using your events as the base for **any** model in your application. Regardless, it's your choice of course, this is just my opinion.

Comment: Implementing your own `Repository` and `AggregateFactory` could be quite some work to be honest, but the framework does allow such modification if desired. I'd recommend dropping a question with AxonIQ directly for this if you feel this is the right way to go. Pretty sure they're willing to discuss an approach with you.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I can answer some of them, but I'm also not really experienced in using Axon:

**Return values from command handler** - Yes, thats possible. We had an example where we return the generated aggregate id (I'm not 100% sure about this answer)

**Local vs remote domain events publication** - Yes, Axon Server ENTERPRISE (!) supports multi-context thats build for this purpose. https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axon-server-enterprise

**CQRS synchronously** - The question is not totally clear but it's not necessary to model your complete system with CQRS. You can use CQRS for some domains and other architecture for subdomains.

Use Saga's for any kind of "transaction" like stuff. Rollbacks should be written by the developer. The system can't do this for you.

**Modular monolith** - Shouldn't be a technical problem.

**Fully separated domain model (persistence agnostic)** - The question is not totally clear but store only events in Axon Server. Aggregates are build up by a sequence of aggregates. Don't use any other data for it. The aggregate are used to do the command handling with state checks and apply new events.

I a system gets a command message, Axon Framework will look at the aggregate id and re-creates the aggregate by replay all the existing events for that aggregate. Then the method for @CommandHandler and command message type is called on the aggregate with the state of the system. Don't do this by yourself.

On the other hand. Create own custom projections (view models) by listening to the events (@EventHandler) and store the data in your own format to any kind of data models/repository. You can for example build a REST api on top of this to use the data.

**Axon Server** - Use it where it's built for. Use it as event store and not for other purposes.

See for more info and why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUSWsJteRfw